# Unknown capability error

Tags: linux

I am trying to cross compile the ipsectools(ipsec-tools-0.8.2) downloaded from opensource for the mips architecture.

I downloaded ipsectools from : https://sourceforge.net/projects/ipsec-tools/

and applied a patch as mentioned in : https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/net/ipsec-tools/patches/006-linux-3.7-compat.patch?rev=35312

Susequently after extracting and applying patch, i used the following commands,

> ./bootstrap
>
> autoconf
>
> ./configure --enable-security-context=no CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}as AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}nm OBJCOPY=${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy OBJDUMP=${CROSS_COMPILE}objdump RANLIB=${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib READELF=${CROSS_COMPILE}readelf STRIP=${CROSS_COMPILE}strip --host=mips-wrs-linux-gnu --build=i586-wrs-linux-gnu

Now if i crosscompile for mips architecture it compiles successfully for mips. But the racoon binary file created shows following

[samb@bhlinv09 racoon]$ file racoon

racoon: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS64 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, with unknown capability 0x410000000f676e75 = 0x1000000070403, not stripped

Can anyone tell me what is this "unknown capability error"?